# IotHub Devices created via PowerShell not displaying

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-iot-sdk, azure-sdk

I'm creating Azure Iot hub devices both on the portal and via powershell.
The devices created on the portal are displayed in the list of devices of the Iot hub,

but the devices created by Powershell's

```
Add-AzIotHubDevice -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -IotHubName $iothubName -DeviceId $id -AuthMethod "shared_private_key" -EdgeEnabled
```

are not displayed on the portal although I can't create a device with Id used by powershell.

I tried to log out and then log in - no luck.

It looks like the devices created by Powershell cmdlet are "somewhere" because Id's are busy.

Comment: I’d be raising that with Microsoft.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the list in the portal? And just to verify: that Powershell command will create an Azure IoT Edge device, which isn't in the list of Devices but in the  IoT Edge section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the requirement we have tried the same to create a new ***IotHub and adding a device to it using Powershell*** --version 7.2.1 .

The cmdlet you are using which will ***Create an edge enabled IoT device with default authorization (shared private key).***

Steps we followed :

- [***`Created new IoT device`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-using-powershell#create-an-iot-hub) by using below cmdlets post `az login`

> New-AzIotHub `
> -ResourceGroupName rgname
> -Name IotHubname
> -SkuName S1 -Units 1
> -Location "west us2"

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:-** ***Make sure that you have provided th same location based on your resource group location.***

- Trying to add a new device using the same command that you are using .

  `Add-AzIotHubDevice -ResourceGroupName "RG NAME" -IotHubName "IOTHUB NAME" -DeviceId "myDevice3" -AuthMethod "shared_private_key" -EdgeEnabled`

[image]

- ***Navigate to Azure Portal> IotHub>Iotedge*** after sometime make a reload and check the device which we have created using `powershell`.

[image]

For more information please refer this ***Microsoft Documentation***:- [***Add-AzIotHubDevice***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.iothub/add-aziothubdevice?view=azps-7.3.0)

Comment: Thank you! The -EdgeEnabled parameter is the answer